# 0xc00000142 при запуске компилятора из-под текстового редактора

Tags: windows-10

Ситуация - новая машина, дозрел до Windows 10.

Имею очень древнюю привычку (и не хочу от нее отказываться - поэтому советы перейти на другой софт, пользоваться тем-то или тем-то - не принимаются) - работать в текстовом режиме. Очень много лет это была такая связка: в bat'нике командной строки Visual С++ добавлялся в конце вызов Far. В нем ассоциированным с С++ редактором шел древний FTE. Из него, в свою очередь, вызывался компилятор, который спокойно компилировал в командной строке, возвращал ошибки в FTE - словом, приятная для глаз :) текстовая среда.

Когда я все это поставил на Windows 10 - по отдельности все вроде бы работает (кстати, был интересный момент... пришлось поизвращаться, чтоб Far был обычного цвета - если просто сделать ярлык и запустить - он получается очень уж ярким), но при попытке компиляции - "Ошибка при запуске приложения 0xc00000142".

По отдельности компилятор, редактор, Far - работают. В комплекте - никак. Подозреваю, что тут что-то может быть связано с пайпами передачи сообщений от компилятора редактору.

Поскольку с Windows 10 дела как-то до этого не имел, надеюсь, что есть какое-то очень простое решение. Есть какие-то идеи, какое? :)

Comment: Проблема может быть в отсутствии Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable или отсутствии нужного .net фреймворка.

Comment: @nick_gabpe Сам компилятор в командной строке запускается нормально, редактор тоже. Не работает связка...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может быть, кому-то пригодится для чего-то другого.

Итак, нужно в свойствах консольного окна пометить флажок *Использовать прежнюю версию консоли*

Почему это мешает жизни? не знаю :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, примерно поэтому или что-то типа того https://habr.com/post/420853/ (хотя обратную совместимость обещали...)