# Исходники в шаблоне проекта Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Раз уж никто не смог ответить на вопрос об [FTE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866479/0xc00000142-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)...
Мне не нравится масса настроек по умолчанию в проектах Visual C++. Решил сделать стандартную заготовку под себя - создал проект, тщательно выставил свойства, *создал исходник с шаблонным текстом*, включенный в проект. Сохранил как шаблон. Все есть, все открывается, проект создается.

Нет только моего файла-заготовки с исходным кодом. При попытках самостоятельно добавить его в .zip и прописать как `<ProjectItem>`, он вроде бы указывается в проекте, но при попытке его открыть, сообщается, что такого файла нет (и его и в самом деле нет в созданном каталоге).

Почему-то этот вопрос совершенно обойден вниманием в Интернете (по крайней мере, найти ответ мне не удалось).

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как заставить создавать исходник (с именем, выбранным для проекта), и чтоб он автоматически был открыт в окне редактора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была такая же проблема. Моё решение было таковым:

1. Создаем шаблон проекта обычным способом с нужными нам параметрами проекта и т.д.
2. Идём по пути `Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates` и находим там наш архив с шаблоном. ( В этом моменте я долго мучился, т.к. VS при экспортировании открывала мне папку `Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates`, но работает она не с этой папкой)
3. Добавляем в наш архив отсутствующие файлы исходников с шаблонным текстом
4. Изменяем в этом архиве файл `.vstemplate` добавлением как вы и говорили `<ProjectItem>` подобным образом (не забудьте изменить свои наименования) :

До:

```
<Project TargetFileName="Project.vcxproj" File="Project.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">Project.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

После:

```
<Project TargetFileName="Project.vcxproj" File="Project.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">Project.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="main.cpp">main.cpp</ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

5. Перезагружаем VS

А что бы элемент автоматически открывался, добавляем атрибут `OpenInEditor="true"` в `<ProjectItem>`:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="main.cpp" OpenInEditor="true">main.cpp</ProjectItem>
```

Comment: Сработало :) Но... "Как мёд - так ложкой" - если я заменяю на `TargetFileName="$projectname$.cpp"`, то ничего не работает... Ему можно как-то объяснить, что в шаблоне исходник надо назвать по имени проекта? И еще - хотелось бы в файле исходника иметь комментарий со временем/датой создания, например. Какие-то макросы на эту тему есть? Ну, и последнее - а указать, где должен курсор стоять в файле заготовки при открытии редактора - как насчет этого? Чтоб не в начале, а поближе к концу... :)